# Spinnaker Error fetching pipelines from Front50: http://:8080/pipelines

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose, spinnaker

I am trying out the Spinnaker using docker-compose.. It ran well, however I am getting the following error while loading the application list.

```
gate        | 2015-11-24 14:36:58.095  INFO 1 --- [readScheduler-1] c.n.s.gate.services.ApplicationService   : Refreshed Application List
echo        | 2015-11-24 14:37:00.307 ERROR 1 --- [  Retrofit-Idle] c.n.s.e.pipelinetriggers.PipelineCache   : Error fetching pipelines from   Front50: http://:8080/pipelines
echo        | 2015-11-24 14:37:10.308 ERROR 1 --- [  Retrofit-Idle] c.n.s.e.pipelinetriggers.PipelineCache   : Error fetching pipelines from Front50: http://:8080/pipelines
echo        | 2015-11-24 14:37:20.309 ERROR 1 --- [  Retrofit-Idle] c.n.s.e.pipelinetriggers.PipelineCache   : Error fetching pipelines from Front50: http://:8080/pipelines
echo        | 2015-11-24 14:37:22.428  INFO 1 --- [ool-12-thread-1] .s.e.s.a.p.i.PipelineConfigsPollingAgent : Running the pipeline configs polling agent...
echo        | 2015-11-24 14:37:30.311 ERROR 1 --- [  Retrofit-Idle] c.n.s.e.pipelinetriggers.PipelineCache   : Error fetching pipelines from Front50: http://:8080/pipelines
echo        | 2015-11-24 14:37:40.312 ERROR 1 --- [  Retrofit-Idle] c.n.s.e.pipelinetriggers.PipelineCache   : Error fetching pipelines from Front50: http://:8080/pipelines
echo        | 2015-11-24 14:37:50.313 ERROR 1 --- [  Retrofit-Idle] c.n.s.e.pipelinetriggers.PipelineCache   : Error fetching pipelines from Front50: http://:8080/pipelines
echo        | 2015-11-24 14:37:52.428  INFO 1 --- [ool-12-thread-1] .s.e.s.a.p.i.PipelineConfigsPollingAgent : Running the pipeline configs polling agent...
gate        | 2015-11-24 14:37:58.096  INFO 1 --- [readScheduler-1] c.n.s.gate.services.ApplicationService   : Refreshing Application List
gate        | 2015-11-24 14:37:58.096  INFO 1 --- [-applications-9] c.n.s.g.s.internal.Front50Service        : ---> HTTP GET http://front50:8080/credentials
gate        | 2015-11-24 14:37:58.098  INFO 1 --- [-applications-9] c.n.s.g.s.internal.Front50Service        : <--- HTTP 200 http://front50:8080/credentials (1ms)
gate        | 2015-11-24 14:37:58.100  INFO 1 --- [applications-10] c.n.s.g.s.internal.Front50Service        : ---> HTTP GET http://front50:8080/global/applications
gate        | 2015-11-24 14:37:58.101  INFO 1 --- [-applications-9] c.n.s.g.services.internal.OortService    : ---> HTTP GET http://clouddriver:7002/applications?expand=false
gate        | 2015-11-24 14:37:58.103  INFO 1 --- [applications-10] c.n.s.g.s.internal.Front50Service        : <--- HTTP 200 http://front50:8080/global/applications (2ms)
gate        | 2015-11-24 14:37:58.105  INFO 1 --- [-applications-9] c.n.s.g.services.internal.OortService    : <--- HTTP 200 http://clouddriver:7002/applications?expand=false (4ms)
```

Application listing and create application features are keeps on loading.. My docker containers are working fine.. Just to add, I hope you guys know gate and echo are container names as mentioned at [github link](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/tree/master/experimental/docker-compose)

Please see my docker ps response. Hope this would help

```
root@leo-OptiPlex-3020:/home/leo# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
002a9446bd73        spinnaker/gate          "/opt/gate/bin/gate"   27 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes       0.0.0.0:8084->8084/tcp   gate                
4a3b05629cdd        spinnaker/orca          "/opt/orca/bin/orca"   27 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes       0.0.0.0:8083->8083/tcp   orca                
b099f638af4e        spinnaker/echo          "/opt/echo/bin/echo"   27 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes       0.0.0.0:8089->8089/tcp   echo                
deefb9583f57        spinnaker/clouddriver   "/opt/clouddriver/bi   28 minutes ago      Up 28 minutes       0.0.0.0:7002->7002/tcp   clouddriver         
cd5c8b8f3c6e        spinnaker/deck          "/bin/sh -c 'npm sta   28 minutes ago      Up 28 minutes       0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp   deck                
9857ab5bdd4d        spinnaker/front50       "/opt/front50/bin/fr   51 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   front50             
d59429d6d06f        spinnaker/rosco         "/opt/rosco/bin/rosc   5 hours ago         Up 28 minutes       0.0.0.0:8087->8087/tcp   rosco               
be5ec6d9ac20        redis                   "/entrypoint.sh redi   5 hours ago         Up 28 minutes       6379/tcp                 redis               
0459b261107e        spinnaker/rush          "/opt/rush/bin/rush"   6 hours ago         Up 28 minutes       0.0.0.0:8085->8085/tcp   rush
```

Thanks in advance in helping me to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the DOCKER_IP environment variable is not set. Try `` DOCKER_IP=`docker-machine ip default` docker-compose up -d ``

Comment: Thank you.. it likely worked because it doesnt throw any errors now.. but the application listing or create application is still keeps "loading".. do I have to configure AWS user there to get the "create application" working.. if so, can I have a doc or link on how to configure it.. thanks